# "Let's go somewhere" vs "let's go anywhere"?

Tags: adverbs

Are these two sentences grammatically correct and do they carry the same meaning? My textbook suggests 1 as the correct form but 2 sounds ok as well to me.

1. Let's go somewhere warm and sunny.
2. Let's go anywhere warm and sunny.

Comment: Search this site for similar questions.

Comment: Dario, re your first question, what do you think might make either of them ungrammatical? Re your second question, what do you understand the difference between *somewhere* and *anywhere* to be? NB if you're not fluent in English, you should find our other site [ell.se] is helpful. :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can understand your concern,but we humans are *social animals* and hence our sentences need to sound polite. And therefore **'Let's go somewhere warm and sunny.' is the correct alternative.**

Saying 'somewhere' indicates that we are giving a good status/value to the place we are referring. Also, it indicates we are asking the other person to spend time with us in a 'specific' place (which is supposed to be good) not just any place, which makes the other person feel important.

The word 'anywhere' isn't grammatically wrong but as a polite gesture it isn't very satisfying. It can be warm and sunny near a trash can too? *Right?*

But 'somewhere' always refers to a specific place worth visiting like a park, open surrounding etc. in a warm and sunny weather.

*Hope this answer helped...*

Comment: Thanks @Riya Agarwal. It indeed helped and I think I got the slight difference in meaning between the two. I especially liked the part _we human are social animal_ :)